# Posting Json string to web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I'm quite new to handling json data and web apis but I'm currently creating an application to further my knowledge on them.

At the moment I can do get requests and these work fine however I'm having issues with posts. I'm trying to post json data to Jira Confluence to create a new page.

On https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples it gives the below code to make a curl request

```js
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page", 
"ancestors":[{"id":456}], "space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":
"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' 
http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

I am currently using the below code and it comes back with a status 200 but I don't see the created page on confluence. I was wondering if anyone could help me out

```
HttpClient _webRequest = new HttpClient();
byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
_webRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
_webRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
string response = "{\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"new page\",\"ancestors\":[{\"id\":40635756}],\"space\":{\"key\":\"VG\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>This is a new page</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}}}"

var content = new StringContent(lol, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = _webRequest.PostAsync("http://jirasite/confluence/rest/api/content/", content).Result;
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's going wrong with the given information. Can you run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), capture the request/response and post the content here?

Comment: new StringContent(lol, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); I dont see "lol" defined here. does it have any significance here?

Comment: Hi sorry instead of lol, I used response string. I used fiddler and it shows a 301 response so I think the API might have moved but on the confluence website it still shows the API as the same location

https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you get 200 status code as mentioned above?

Comment: The 200 was just to say it was sent I think, when I loaded up fiddler I saw the 200 request and then a 301 response as well

Answer (score -1):

Your auth header looks incorrect... You are missing the whitespace after "**Basic**" it should be like this "**Basic xxx**".

Please take a look at the following document:

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples?_ga=2.72183699.1804458933.1496916716-1816616270.1496916716#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Createanewpage

Regards

Craig

Comment: The headers were fine, the issue was that they have moved the API to

/wiki/rest/api/content/

Comment: Furthermore, this answer is false. `System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue` takes a scheme as a second parameter. Scheme `Basic` is valid!
If this wasn't the answer, please don't mark it as accepted. Answer your own question and mark it.-